# GQL resolver: returning null

Tags: javascript, graphql, resolver

I'm calling data from an API and have a resolver that looks like this:

```
Query: {
    async getSomething(parent, args, ctx, info) {
      const kek = yada.aol.emails(function (err, res) {
            return[{name: "lmao"}]
            // returns null every time
        })
      return [{name: "lol"}]
      // returns correctly
    },
  },
```

However, the data I need to return would be the response within the function. I was wondering as to why anything I return that's nested in that function returns `null` and how I can continue to shape the data appropriately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `namecheap.domains.getList` function is asynchronous. Your last `return` is executed before the callback `function (err, res) {}`. You need to return a Promise.

Either `namecheap.domains.getList` supports Promises and you can return it directly (but I don't know what that is), or you can make the callback function resolve a Promise:

```js
  Query: {
    getDomains(parent, args, ctx, info) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        namecheap.domains.getList((err, res) => {
          if (err) return reject(err);
          resolve(res);
        })
      });
    },
  },
```

Comment: I edited the question to be a little more specific, if you don't mind tailoring your answer to completely guide me through this!

Comment: Ok, I've updated the answer (in the new code in your question, replace the inside `return` with `resolve(res);` - or `resolve([{name: "lol"}]);` depending on what you want to return)